# .po file for default cakephp libs translations

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, poedit, po

How to add the translations for cakephp libs files to by default.po file
for example
- months name
- day's name
- timeAgoInWords

i try to add strings to default.po manually
but everytime i update it from default.pot (using poedit)
the strings are gone.

please help me to solve it
it will fine to find solution by using separate .po file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve it
- create /app/views/dummy.ctp
- duplicate by coping the translation from cake\libs\view\helpers\time.ctp to dummy.ctp
- and cake i18n will add translations to default.pot

Answer (score 0):

You can see the relevant strings for `timeAgoInWords` [at the end of `TimeHelper::timeAgoInWords`](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/time-helper/#l-577). They're just normal translation strings along the lines of `'year'`, `'years'`, `'month'`, `'months'` etc, just put these translations into the general domain .po file.

There's one special case where a full date string may be printed like `'on 18/2/09'`. The "on" can be localized by localizing the string `'on %s'`, but the date format needs to be passed to the `timeAgoInWords` function:

```
$this->Time->timeAgoInWords($time, array('format' => __('Y-m-d', true)));
```

The month names [follow the same schema](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper/#l-2120), just add translations for `'January'`, `'February'`, etc in your general domain translation file. Not quite sure where Cake outputs the *day* that would need to be translated though. Please elaborate.

Comment: that is ok with translations but how to put them to separate file. i know that i can use the domain solution for making separate files
but it not the way to edit cake\libs\view\helpers\time.php to adding domain

Comment: @baur Ah, now I see what you're asking. Yeah, short of editing or overriding the Cake method there's no real solution, I'm afraid. You'll need to be more careful merging new translations into your existing file... :-/