# Cakephp 2.4 isn't reading .po files

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I created the following file :
/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

Content:

```
msgid "delete"
msgstr "effacer"
```

I set the the default language to fra in core.php

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');
```

when i use

```
<h3><?php echo __("delete"); ?></h3>
```

the output should be "effacer" which isn't the case

I tried importing i18n class and setting i10n manually but the issue persist

```
App::import('I18n', 'i18n');
$I18n =& I18n::getInstance();
$I18n->l10n->get($this->params['lang']);
```

When i check the persistent cache "myapp_cake_core_default_fra" i find an empty array

Comment: Did you edit your .po file manually? Or did you use a special PO Editor? Try http://www.poedit.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [.po file for default cakephp libs translations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465486/po-file-for-default-cakephp-libs-translations)

Answer (score 0):

Set this language code with language parameter
 Configure::write('Config.language','en_Us');